# How to apply radial spatial filter on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, spatial, radial

I have images that contain a series of concentric circles (artifacts), so I would like to apply some kind of radial spatial filter in order to smoothen these circles.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Regards,

Simon

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Find the center of the image using center of mass calculations
2. Transform the image to polar coordinates (ImToPolar, need to download).
3. Filter in the radial direction (this would be a 1D filter in the x direction).
4. Transform back to cartesian coordinates.